# Upgrading from Sitecore 7.2 to Sitecore 9 on Virtual Machine windows 10

Tags: upgrade, sitecore-install-framework

We are about to upgrade from **Sitecore 7.2** to **Sitecore 9.0** and we are planning to do the Sitecore upgrade in **Virtual Machine Windows 10** and we never did this before on VM, we used to work on our desktops only. We will use the express migration tool to perform the upgrade.

We are brainstorming on challenges that we could face on going with the upgrade on VM.

1) Are there any documents available online to explain about the PRO's and CON's of going with upgrade on Virtual Machine especially for upgrading to SItecore 9?

2) Has anyone done it before? and faced any challenges? or there are any suggestions?

Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: A virtual machine is much like a local machine, there is nothing special about it in that regards. If you were upgrading PaaS then it would be different but in terms of upgrading it should be much the same as local.

Comment: I am always using Windows Server instead of VM to be as close as possible to client server landscape. There are couple of things you need to consider: a) Do you have lots of customizations? -> If yes, you need to take a look what are equivalent classes in latest Sitecore and you need to adjust code (inheritance, maybe obsolete classes). 2) Are you heavily using DMS? -> Take a look on XConnect API introduced in Sitecore 9 and code changes will be needed. Goals are trigged differently from code as previously.

Comment: You should be fine using Express migration tool. good luck

Comment: considering the fact you are using VM. the migration being a slow process will  be even more slow. Try installing SC9 on win10, and crete instance of your SC7.2 on it as well. you can easily use both of the instances on the same machine. You dont need VM for it. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration tool will have no difference using a standard VM than if you execute it locally, other than latency if you are doing things across a network or resource issues if you don't have enough CPU or RAM as you have on your local system.

Obviously, it also depends on the hardware your VM is running on. If the hardware is not as efficient as your local system, you may see worse performance. This is not because your are using a VM, just things to consider when you are working not on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between VM and Desktop. please make sure that Sitecore 9 prerequisites are there/installed.

- Microsoft PowerShell® version 5.0 or later
- Web Platform Installer 5.0
- URL Rewrite 2.1
- Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DAC Fx) version 17.1
- Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom
- Java JRE
- Solr

Comment: Thank you Shehata for providing with the configuration details.